# mod rewrite problem?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite this url:

```
http://www.example.com/user.php?user=username
```

into

```
http://example.com/username
```

I'm using this code in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

but its giving me an internal error. Is there something wrong?

Comment: what does the error log say!! thanks

Comment: If they type exaxmple.com/username/ with a trailing slash do you want it to fail? That might give users problems. Or is a trailing slash optional? Plus: are your usernames expected to be a certain length? And what chars are going to be allowed?

Comment: yes i want it to fail, they are allowed any characters!!

Comment: Well a username like slashy/slashy/slashslash is going to gum up the works slightly isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the query string part of a URL, you have to use RewriteCond, like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} user=(.*)
RewriteRule ^user.php$ %1 [L]
```

So the RewriteCond rule matches the username in ?user=name and then the %1 uses that value in the resulting rewrite on the last line of my example.

On the slash issue, URLs like /name get automatically redirected to URLs like /name/ if the web server finds that /name is a directory.  So if your intention is to map user.php/user=name to something like /name/index.html, you will cause that slash to get inserted.  But if your intention is to map it to a file (or CGI script) at /name then it will work as expected.

Comment: Hmm. After re-reading the question, are you sure you're trying to map user.php?user=username into /username?  Your text says that, but your .htaccess goes the other direction, like you're trying to take the URL /username and map it into user.php?user=username.  So sorry if I answered a question you weren't asking :-)